# Capturing Multitouch in Android

Tags: android, touch

For my games I allways use singletouch so I allways keep track of the Pointer in an onTouch() Method like this:
-get the pointer Id at (0) with event.getPointerId(0); when pId==0, where pId is the pointer Id
-there will be no computation of other pointers when the pId!=-1(standard value I assign when the prime pointer is lifted up again.) and if the current pointer index is not the same as the pointer indes of the pointer Id I have saved in pId

like so:

```
      switch(e.getAction())
      {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if(pID!=-1)break;
            ...
            pID=e.getPointerId(0);
            ...
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if(pID==-1||e.getActionIndex()!=e.findPointerIndex(pID))break;
            ...
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(pID==-1||e.getActionIndex()!=e.findPointerIndex(pID))break;
            ...
            pID=-1;
            ...
            break;
      }
```

But now I stumbled across a code that I wrote 2 weeks ago where I do it other way, because I wanted to react to Multitouch(maximum two touch pointers allowed for zooming):

```
      switch(e.getAction())
      {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if(tP1.getPointerIndex()==-1&&tP2.getPointerIndex()==-1)
            {
                tP1.setPointerIndex(currentPointerIndex);
                mode=Mode.SINGLE;
            }
            else if(tP1.getPointerIndex()!=-1&&tP2.getPointerIndex()==-1&&!isDragging)
            {
                tP2.setPointerIndex(currentPointerIndex);
                mode=Mode.MULTI;
            }

            if(e.findPointerIndex(tP1.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
            {
                tP1.X=e.getX();
                tP1.Y=e.getY();
                tP1.oldX=tP1.X;
                tP1.oldY=tP1.Y;
            }
            else if(e.findPointerIndex(tP2.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
            {
                tP2.X=e.getX();
                tP2.Y=e.getY();
                tP2.oldX=tP2.X;
                tP2.oldY=tP2.Y;
            }
            else break;
            ...
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(e.findPointerIndex(tP1.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
            {
                tP1.X=e.getX();
                tP1.Y=e.getY();
            }
            else if(e.findPointerIndex(tP2.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
            {
                tP2.X=e.getX();
                tP2.Y=e.getY();
            }
            else break;
            ...
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if(e.findPointerIndex(tP1.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
            {
                tP1.X=e.getX();
                tP1.Y=e.getY();
            }
            else if(e.findPointerIndex(tP2.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
            {
                tP2.X=e.getX();
                tP2.Y=e.getY();
            }
            else break;

            if(mode==Mode.SINGLE)
            {
                mode=Mode.NONE;
                tP1.resetPointerIndex();
            }
            else if(mode==Mode.MULTI)
            {
                mode=Mode.SINGLE;
                if(e.findPointerIndex(tP1.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
                {
                    tP1.resetPointerIndex();
                    tP1.setPointerIndex(tP2.getPointerIndex());
                    tP1.X=tP2.X;
                    tP1.Y=tP2.Y;
                    tP1.oldX=tP2.oldX;
                    tP1.oldY=tP2.oldY;
                    tP2.resetPointerIndex();
                }
                else if(e.findPointerIndex(tP2.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
                {
                    tP2.resetPointerIndex();
                }
            }
            break;
      }
```

tP1 and tP2 ar class objects who keep track of the last x and y coordinates and of the pointer index. So they represent the two pointers. I allways swap the second pointer on the first pointer if the first pointer is raised up and the second is still on. Now it is really embarrassing because I wrote this code for a colleague of mine for a few bucks.

So I jsut keep track of the indices of the pointers but they are sometimes changing. I didnt noticed it because everything was working fine. But now as I came accross it I noticed this. What should I do. Do I need to change it or do you see no problem to let this code be as it is?

I am just assuming that it can go wrong because I dont track the pointer Id but only the pointer Index.

Also I never experience it when testing that for example the primary pointer when first touched get swapped to another index but 0 when another touchpointer comes down.

I feel so dumb that I didnt notice it, so now I need a good advice how to behave pls help...

It is really strange that is code worked because I do this:

```
if(e.findPointerIndex(tP1.getPointerIndex())==currentPointerIndex)
```

So Android not only assigns the index of the first pointer with 0 but also the pointerId with 0. This code is a mess i think